# I wrote a VBA code to input data, but it doesn't work for decimals

Tags: vba, excel, finance

So this is the code, which works only for integers

```
Dim CoupRate As Double
    Do
        CoupRate = InputBox("enter coupon rate in percent without % sign. It must be between 0.00% and 25.00%")
        If CoupRate < 0 Or CoupRate > 25 Then
            MsgBox ("CoupRate must be between 0% and 25%")
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
```

Comment: What should it do? What is the expected behaviour and how is this different from what you are observing?

Comment: Use Comma instead of dot

Comment: @QHarr I need this code to work for coupon rate = 5.25, but it works only for coupon rate = 5

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please Use Comma `,` instead of dot `.`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the decimals in the output as well. Could you please be more specific.

```
    CoupRate = InputBox("enter coupon rate in percent without % sign. It must be between 0.00% and 25.00%")
    If CoupRate < 0 Or CoupRate > 25 Then
        MsgBox ("CoupRate must be between 0% and 25%")
    Else
        'Exit Do
        MsgBox CoupRate & "%"
    End If
```

Comment: Thank you for your consideration) Actually it didn't work for me because I used dot instead of coma)

Comment: Can you try this `Format(CoupRate, "0.00")`